# Modyfing the objects sequence between arrays C# simple solution

Tags: c#, arrays, object, sequences

I was trying to find (using a code listed below) a simple solution for copying all the objects which are stored in first array, to second array, with changing paralelly the index of objects in second array + 1, so the object[0] in first array would be equal to object[1] in second one, and the last object[9] in the first one would be equal to the object[0] in second.

While trying to start code which I've written I've received message, which stated that "Destination array was not long enough Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds", I'm just starting with arrays part at c#, so I'd be very gratefull for any quidance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] first = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
        int[] second = new int[first.Length];

        Array.Copy(first, 0, second, 1, 10);
        foreach (int x in second)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Array.Copy` and `foreach` you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    second[i == first.Length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1] = first[i];
```

It just goes from `i = 0` to `i = first.Length-1`, copying the element at that index in `first` to that index plus 1 in `second`.

Comment: Thank You very much for this solution, as I was thinking about the easiest possible way of doing it by loop, I'll surely analyze this one : )

Comment: @ArturS Yeah, personally I've never seen the need for any of `Array`'s methods. Making my own loops seems so much more clear most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

If the idea is to rotate the array one position forward, you can use a simple for:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] first = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
    int[] second = new int[first.Length];

    for (int k = 0; k < first.Length; k++)
        second[(k == (first.Length - 1))? 0: k + 1] = first[k];

    foreach (int x in second)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: The question clearly states that the item in `first` that was at position `first.Length - 1` should be moved to index `0` in `second`, not index `first.Length` (i.e. `second` should be `first`, but rotated by one index).